# Matlab error message regarding use of polyfit function in script file

Tags: matlab, function, polynomial-math

I am trying to run a script file which draws a line on a plotted graph. Sometimes the script file works but occasionally it does not work and the line drawn on the graph is not where I want it. When the file does not work I get the following error message:

```
Warning: Polynomial is not unique. Degree >= number of data points.
> In polyfit at 70
  In FIXING_force_and_rate_of_rise at 48
```

Does anyone know what this error message means? What does it mean when a polynomial is not unique?

If it helps, when I click on the error message I get taken to this explanation:

Solve least squares problem.

```
[Q,R] = qr(V,0);
ws = warning('off','all'); 
p = R\(Q'*y);    
% Same as p = V\y;
warning(ws);
if size(R,2) > size(R,1)
   warning(message('MATLAB:polyfit:PolyNotUnique'))
elseif warnIfLargeConditionNumber(R)
    if nargout > 2
    warning(message('MATLAB:polyfit:RepeatedPoints'));
    else
        warning(message('MATLAB:polyfit:RepeatedPointsOrRescale'));
    end
```

A section of the code I am trying to run is pasted below. Line 48 is where I think the error is: `[SlpBL2]=polyfit(Time_scale(300:T2), Force_trace(300:T2),1);`

Reject the 1st 300 data points

```
BL1=min(Force_trace(300:end));
col='rcgy'
figure; set(gcf, 'windowstyle', 'docked', 'color', 'w')
for j=1:100
    cla
    Force_trace=Force_trace-BL1;
    Peak1=max(Force_trace(300:end-30));
    Extrapolation_point=Peak1*0.10;
    D=Force_trace<Extrapolation_point;
    T2=find(D,1,'last');
    [SlpBL2]=polyfit(Time_scale(300:T2), Force_trace(300:T2),1);
    Slope=SlpBL2(1);
    BL2=SlpBL2(2);

    plot(Time_scale, Force_trace)
    hold on
    plot([0, Time_scale(T2)], [BL2, Time_scale(T2)*Slope+BL2],col(1))

    disp(['round number ' int2str(j) ' baseline is ' num2str(BL2)])
   if abs(BL2)<1e-10
      break
   end
   BL1=BL2;
   drawnow 
end
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

### Code discussion

Since you are fitting a one-degree polynomial to data, passing less than two data points is the only reason that error would be thrown.
This will happen if `T2` is always `300` or empty (meaning that `D` is all `false`.

### Explanation

In order to exactly fit a polynomial of degree `n`, `n+1` data points are required to uniquely determine the `n+1` coefficients of the polynomial.
For example, a cubic has the form:

[image: cubic polynomial].

A cubic equation requires four points of data to uniquely determine the four coefficients.

With less than `n+1` data points, an exact polynomial can not be created since, assuming there is an underlying function from which the data was drawn, there are an infinite number of solutions.
However, a polynomial whose coefficients form the smallest/shortest solution can readily be calculated; this is the least-squares solution.
[This brief overview](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~amos/412/lecture-notes/lecture17.pdf) (section 2) gives a succinct overview of this and overdetermined solutions, which is more common in my experience.

Consider this input:

```
>> x = linspace(0,1,50);
>> y = x.^3 + x.^2;
>> p3 = polyfit(x([1,25,50]),y([1,25,50]),3);
Warning: Polynomial is not unique; degree >= number of data points. 
> In polyfit at 70 
>> p4 = polyfit(x([1,10,25,50]),y([1,10,25,50]),3);
```

and the plot here:

[image: Graphs of a cubic, an undetermined fit, and an exact fit]

The undetermined solution follows the true function closely but not exactly.

Comment: Hi Troy,

Thank you for your answer, it's helped me better understand where I'm going wrong but I still don't fully understand how to fix my problem. I'm not sure how T2 would always be 300 or empty, making D false. 300 refers to the number of data points I am excluding. I would expect Extrapolation_point to always be higher than the 300th data point (corresponding to the 300th millisecond of data recording), so T2 would be very close to extrapolation_point. I'm still a bit confused about where I need to change my code (sorry, you'll have to excuse my elementary maths and code skills!)

Comment: Perhaps the 'find' function which finds the value of point T2 is not working as I would expect... That's what I'm going to look at next, any other ideas are greatly appreciated.